# Return to previous ShowInputDialog after ShowMessageDialog

Tags: java, swing

There will be a ShowInputDialog box for user to key in numbers. When user keys in character it will show a MessageDialog box to indicate invalid input.

How do I return to the previous showInputDialog for user to reenter the number after the user click on "OK" button on the MessageDialog box?

The codes:

```
public static void addStock(Stock s[],int index)
{
    s[index] = new Stock();

    try{
        s[index].setNumber(Double.parseDouble(showInputDialog(null,"Enter number: ")));

    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input. Enter digits only.", "Error!",ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

*Edit: It is an inventory system using dialog boxes as the interface to interact with user. For example, to add,delete,update stock in the system.

Comment: Show something that you have done for this problem?

Comment: What is this in, a web-app. desktop app. applet..?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"Edit: It is an inventory system.."*  That does not answer my question, in case that was your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
boolean isValSet = false;

while(!isValSet)
{ 
    try {
        String val=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter number: ");
        double parseDouble = Double.parseDouble(val);

        //set you parseDouble to your attribute.
        isValSet=true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input. Enter digits only.", "Error!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mellissa I just fixed the indentation of the code. The answer belongs to sachin pasalkar. Your welcome anyway ;)